# Show $(S_L)^L$ is the closed linear span of $S$ and prove or disprove that $(T^L)_L$ is the closed linear span of $T$

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $E$ be a normed vector space. For $S \subseteq E$ let $S_L$ denote $\{\phi \in E^*: \phi(x)=0 \forall x\in S\}$ and for $T\subseteq E^*$ denote $T^L=\{x\in E| \phi(x)=0 \forall \phi \in T$} Show $(S_L)^L$ is the closed linear span of $S$ and prove or disprove that $(T^L)_L$ is the closed linear span of $T$

First note that $S_L=\{\phi| \overline{SpanS}\subseteq \ker(\phi)\}$ and $T^L=\cap_{\phi \in T} \ker\phi$. First i show that $(S_L)^L=\overline{SpanS}$. It is clear that $\overline{SpanS}\subseteq (S_L)^L$ using the noted "new" definitions. Now let $x \not \in \overline{SpanS}$ then take the subspace generated by $\overline{SpanS}$ and $x$ and by hanh banach we can define a linear functional that has $\overline{SpanS}$ as kernel and $x$ is not in the kernel. Thus $x \not \in (S_L)^L$ as desired.

Trouble comes with the second statement. I think I showed that $\overline{SpanT}\subset (T^L)_L$ but I could not show the reverse direction. It is clear $Span(T)\subseteq (T^L)_L$ we also know that $(T^L)_L$ is closed since if $f_n \to f$ in norm, then also they converge pointwise, but if $f_n(x)=0 \forall n$ then $f(x)=0$. Is the reverse inclusion true or what is the counterexample?

Comment: Can you please define $K$.

Comment: @Zeta-Squared not sure why i wrote $K$ it is supposed to be $S$ wqill fix it now

Comment: There is something a little off about your argument for the first part. I believe your use of Hahn-Banach is incorrect. If we consider $\text{span}(\overline{\text{span}(S)},x)$ then as you say you can define a linear functional which is the extension of some $\phi\in S_{L}$ that is non-zero at $x$, however, you could also extend trivially by $0$ and then $\phi(x)=0$ in which case this contradicts your conclusion.

Comment: So now that I have had time to think about it, I believe your first argument is fine, albeit it could use some tidying up. Also it seems you could use the same argument on the second part by consider all the $x$ as members of $E^{**}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to prove that $(T^L)_L$ is the weak$^*$-closure of $T$ in $E^*$. If $x^*\in T$ then $x^*(x)=0$ for every $x\in T^L$ so $T\subseteq (T^L)_L$. On the other hand, $(T^L)_L$ is weak$^*$ closed in $E^*$ so $\overline T^w\subseteq (T^L)_L$. Now, if $x^*\neq \overline T^w$, then the Hahn-Banach theorem gives us an $x\in T^L$ such that $x^*(x)\neq 0.$ That is, $x^*\neq (T^L)_L$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I am not very fluent with $weak*$ topology. Could you perhaps explain it some other way? From what i understand $(T^L)_L$ is in fact equal to the closure of the span, correct? So all that is left to do (as i showed the other inclusion myself) is to show that if $x \not \in$ closure of the span of $T$ then $x \not in  (T^L)_L$

Comment: $(T^L)_L$ is a subset of $E^*$, and it is convenient to use the weak$^*$ topology because then Hahn-Banach can be applied, as in my answer.  To define this topology, take the family of functionals $x(f)=f(x)$ for each $x\in E$ and declare a set $0\in A\subseteq E$ to be open if it is a union of finite intersections of sets of the form $\{f:|x(f)|<\epsilon\}$. Then, by translation, you get a topology on $E^*$. Now, by construction, convergence in this topology  is just pointwise: $f_n\to f$ if and only of $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for each $x\in E$.